# How to do kerberos authentication with a python suds client

Tags: python, kerberos, suds, gssapi

I have a Windows-based web service that does certificate revocation. It supplies a WSDL file that I want the python `suds` package to use to allow me to revoke certificates.

The service is protected via Kerberos/GSSAPI, so there is a keytab file in order to provide the credentials. How do I tell the `suds` client to use the keytab file to provide the credentials to the web service?

In other words, I want to do something like this:

```
from suds.client import Client
url = 'https://example.com/CertificateManagement/IssuedCertificateService.svc?wsdl'
t = HttpAuthKerberosKeytab('/path/to/file.keytab') 
client = Client(url, transport=t)
print client
```

Answer (score 0):

You will require PyKerberos. If your client does not, you have to patch it. Otherwise there will be not SPNEGO/Kerberos support for your web services.